# Pasting 1d array into 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to paste an array of custom class instances into a 2d array of them in a specific position with this code:

```
arr.Array.SetValue(stripe, topleft.X, topleft.Y);
```

…and it gives me a `System.InvalidCastException` with the message `Object cannot be stored in an array of this type.`

`arr.Array` is `MyClass[,]`, and `stripe` is `MyClass[]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

This line of code is a part of a larger method that loads a rectangular piece of map for a 2d platformer. The goal is to load separate stripes of tiles into a 2d array so that they form a rectangle of certain dimensions within the 2d array of tiles of larger dimensions.

Of course, this can be done bit by bit, but isn't there some method that allows to do that?

Comment: You will need to show the object types, the array an the object you put into the array.

Comment: I think the array should be defined as `MyClass[,][]` instead.

Comment: A 2d array of 1d arrays? I'm making a game with a 2d tile map, why would I need that?

Comment: you are trying to insert an array into a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Maybe I'm using a wrong method. What I want is to copy a horizontal sequence of elements into a 2d array beginning from `topleft`.

Comment: try Array.Copy(stripe, 0, arr, topleft.X * topleft.Y)

Comment: @muratgu `System.RankException: The specified arrays must have the same number of dimensions.`

Comment: please provide us with a more detailed visualisation of what the 2d array should look like at the end.

Comment: Guess, you need to specify the array index of `stripe` like `arr.Array.SetValue(stripe[index], topleft.X, topleft.Y);`

Comment: Consider using a jagged array `MyClass[][]` instead of a 2D array. Then you can `Array.Copy()` to/from the rows.

Comment: @ja72 but then it will also become slower than a 2d array, which is undesirable

Comment: @user1306322, I disagree. 2D arrays are the slowest. The fastest is a long 1D array with the rows in sequence such that `this[i,j] = array[i*(columns)+j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you use a long 1d array instead of a 2d array. Here is an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int rows = 100, cols = 100;
    // array has rows in sequence
    // for example:
    //  | a11 a12 a13 |    
    //  | a21 a22 a23 | = [ a11,a12,a13,a21,a22,a23,a31,a32,a33]
    //  | a31 a32 a33 |    
    MyClass[] array=new MyClass[rows*cols];
    // fill it here

    MyClass[] stripe=new MyClass[20];
    // fill it here

    //insert stripe into row=30, column=10
    int i=30, j=10;
    Array.Copy(stripe, 0, array, i*cols+j, stripe.Length);

}
```

Comment: Maybe I will. I'll just need to create a class that will handle the old 2d array calls and transform them into 1d array calls internally. Then I'll be able to insert the stripes of tiles easily.

Comment: Just make sure you check the length of the stripe versus how many element remain until the next row.

Answer (score 0):

> System.InvalidCastException with the message Object cannot be stored
>   in an array of this type.

You would have to mention the `index` of `stripe` array, from which you might have to copy the value.

```
    class MyClass
    {
         public string Name {get;set;}
    }
```

Usage:

```
   // Creates and initializes a one-dimensional array.
    MyClass[] stripe = new MyClass[5];

    // Sets the element at index 3.
    stripe.SetValue(new MyClass() { Name = "three" }, 3);


    // Creates and initializes a two-dimensional array.
    MyClass[,] arr = new MyClass[5, 5];

    // Sets the element at index 1,3.
    arr.SetValue(stripe[3], 1, 3);

    Console.WriteLine("[1,3]:   {0}", arr.GetValue(1, 3));
```

Comment: I guess this is not faster than doing double `for` loops and copying one by one?

Comment: @user1306322: About speed, why do you need a double `for`. You could loop only `stripe`.. Sorry if I am not in context..

Comment: You're right. I was thinking about pasting a list of all stripes.

Comment: Each `stripe` index should have a definite location in the `arry` right? which is not arranged in order/sequential?

Comment: map is in a binary file, tiles are saved row after row and the stripes are horizontal lines of specified length. They form a rectangle smaller than the map.